# PHP loose typing in while loop comparison

Tags: php, loops, loose-typing

Given the following code snippet:

```
  $i= 11;
  function get_num() {
    global $i;
    return (--$i >= 0) ? $i : false;
  }
  while($num = get_num()) {
    echo "Number: $num\n";
  }
```

Results in the following output:

```
Number: 10
Number: 9
Number: 8
Number: 7
Number: 6
Number: 5
Number: 4
Number: 3
Number: 2
Number: 1
```

However, I also want it to output `Number: 0` - but the while loop evaluates `0` as being `false`, so the loop never gets to that point. How do I get the loop to terminate only on an explicit `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while( ($num = get_num()) !== false ) {
```

extra = forces type check as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $i= 11;
  function get_num() {
    global $i;
    return (--$i >= 0) ? $i : false;
  }
  while(($num = get_num())!==false) {
    echo "Number: $num\n";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a **comparison that compares the types**, and not only the values -- which means using the `===` or `!==` operators, instead of `==` or `!=`.

So, you could use something like :

```
while(($num = get_num()) !== false) {
    echo "Number: $num\n";
}
```

With this, `0` will not be considered as the same thing as `false`.

As reference : [**Comparison Operators**][1] *(quoting)*

> `$a == $b` : **Equal** : `TRUE` if
> `$a` is equal to `$b`. 
> `$a === $b`
> : **Identical** : `TRUE` if `$a` is
> equal to `$b`, **and they are of the
> same type**.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using `global`.  Some devs scream about using `global` when not necessary.  Also, you can leave out the parentheses if you write `false!==` before your `$num` declaration (no big deal, just a note).

Option 1

```
function get_num() {
    static $i=11;  // effectively only declare the value once
    return (--$i >= 0) ? $i : false;
}
while(false!==$num=get_num()){
    echo "Number: $num\n";  // $i is NOT available outside the scope of the function.
}
```

Option 2

```
function get_num($i) {
    return (--$i >= 0) ? $i : false;
}
$num=11;  // declare in global scope
while(false!==$num=get_num($num)){  // pass it to function as an argument
    echo "Number: $num\n";
}
```